# How to use ArrayAdapter and JSONArray for a listView

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

So far I can send a Get request to a server with a letter added to the url :

```
private void GetDevice() {

    String deviceId = editTextDeviceId.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceId)){
        editTextDeviceId.setError("Please enter deviceId");
        editTextDeviceId.requestFocus();
    }

    HashMap<String, String>params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("deviceID", deviceId);

    PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(Api.URL_GETBYDEVICEID + deviceId, null, CODE_GET_REQUEST);
    request.execute();

}
```

When I press the button Search it sends the request :

```
buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            GetDevice();
        }
    });
```

The server response is JSONArray :

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"DeviceId":"T","TransactionValue":2,"RSSI":2,"Time":"2018-08-02T14:43:00"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Here is my problem.
From what I read, I know I need to use an ArrayList and ArrayAdapter to convert it into a JSONObject. Am I right so far ?

Here is where I’m stuck, as I don’t understand how to do it.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Look like you are try to convert string json to JSONObject, but string result is a JSONArray

Comment: I mean it is what I understand, but at this point I'm very confuse.

Comment: How's your List Data adapter look like?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string returned from the server is a Json array,

so you need to convert it to a Jsonarray as follows, the jsonString here is the JSON string returned.

```java
        try {
            JSONArray array=new JSONArray(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Yes but you're sure it doesn't involve ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: The server returns the JSON array, you need to convert it to array adapter to show in a listview but that's not the issue that you are having. How to show data in a listview, take a look here, https://github.com/MustafizurRahman/ListViewExample

Comment: This is what your error is, type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

The param you send is a `JSONArray` ,and the param that the server needs is a `JSONObject`.
The structure of `JSONObject` is like `{  }`,and a `JSONArray` is like `[ { } , { } , ......  , { } ]`.So, you can change your param to `{"DeviceId":"T","TransactionValue":2,"RSSI":2,"Time":"2018-08-02T14:43:00"}`  or edit the code of the server to receive parameters with `JSONArray`.

Comment: I wish I could but I don't have access to the server. 
Also I'm sending a GET request not a POST request so I don't send params.

Comment: Ok,I got that wrong. You can have a try with the code:```try {
            org.json.JSONArray jsonArray = new org.json.JSONArray(json);
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**You need to add array adapter**

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i < jArray.length() ; i++) {
json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
String deviceID=json_data.getString("deviceID");
items.add(deviceID);
Log.d(deviceID,"Output"+deviceID);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item, items));
 setListAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
```

add device id in Hashmap it works

Comment: Thank you. Could you be more specific when you say add the device id in Hashmap please ?

Comment: Also I don't see what are the variables jArray, json_data ? Sorry I'm beginning, it's not easy for me.